# Unable to override the ModelForm validation

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms

I am not able to unable to override the Django ModelForm,

forms.py

```
class CustomerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Customer Name '}))
    address = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Customer Address'}))
    phone_number = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Customer Phone Number '}))
    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Customer Email'}))
    contact_person = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Contact person'}))
    amc_date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'ex: Jan 20, 1996'}))
    amc_product = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Products listed in AMC'}))
    warranty_date = forms.DateField(required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'ex: Jan 20, 1996'}))
    warranty_product_list = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Products listed in warranty'}))
    support = forms.ChoiceField(choices=support_choice, required=True,)

    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ['name','address','phone_number','email','contact_person','support','amc_date','amc_product','warranty_date',
                  'warranty_product_list']

    def clean_amc_date(self):
        amc_date = self.cleaned_data.get("amc_date")
        if amc_date == "":
            amc_date = 0
        return amc_date
    def clean_amc_product(self):
        amc_product = self.cleaned_data.get("amc_date")
        if amc_product == "":
            amc_product = 0
        return amc_product
```

on submitting the form, the error shows as "this field is required".

Comment: Which field does it show the error for? What does the `Customer` model look like?

Answer (score 0):

See the docs on [how validators are run in forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/validation/). Basically, the built-in field validation is run before the `clean_*` methods; so if you want to allow blank values at that point, you need to define your fields with `required=False`:

```
amc_date = forms.DateField(required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'ex: Jan 20, 1996'}))
amc_product = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Products listed in AMC'}))
```